# .NET DLL with dynamic web reference in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, app-config

I have a .NET assembly which references a web service. The web reference is set to 'Dynamic' so the reference URL is stored in the app.config file.

This assembly is included in an ASP.NET website to provide certain functionality.

The assembly is built first and then included into the website in the bin folder using a .refresh file.

No app.config file is produced when the assembly is compiled. Therefore how do i go about getting the assembly to load its dynamic web reference from the ASP.NET websites web.config file ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just copy the `app.config` to the folder where the assembly is located, and it should work fine.

See here for details:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/3076bffd-c630-42c6-870a-fa6ca57cefdf

Comment: Does the dll config file need to be called the same as the dll itself ?? i.e. assembly.dll needs assembly.dll.config